# How to identify if a mention in Microsoft Bots Framework in Microsoft Teams is a channel?

Tags: javascript, typescript, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

On Microsoft Bots Framework with Microsoft Teams I can easily get the mentions and store them to later send a proactive message. The example below shows how to get the mentions as per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=typescript).

```
this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
    const mentions = TurnContext.getMentions(turnContext.activity);
    if (mentions){
        const firstMention = mentions[0].mentioned;
        await turnContext.sendActivity(`Hello ${firstMention.name}.`);
    } else {
        await turnContext.sendActivity(`Aw, no one was mentioned.`);
    }

    await next();
});
```

But to send a proactive message I have two different message structures that are used to either send the message to a user or to a channel, thus later in the process when sending the message, I need to know if the `mentions[0]` is a user or a channel.

I had looked in the documentation and in different use cases and couldn't find an answer on how to do that.

Comment: mentions[0].mentioned.id is the chat id between user & bot / bot&channel. the id is conversation id not the user/channel id when you send message using this id i will send the message where bot @mentioned

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ll update the question to be more accurate. But my question remain, how do I identity if the mention is a user or a channel to be able to send a proactive message?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing something similar, as you said I didn't found a straight way to tell the difference between a mention from a user or a team but this is what I used:

```
try {
  // Check if mention is a member of a team
  const member = await TeamsInfo.getMember(
    context,
    mention.mentioned.id
  );
} catch (e) {
  try {
    // Or maybe is a team?
     const team = await TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(
        context,
        mention.mentioned.id
      )
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```